# Navigation not responding to CSS flexbox commands

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass, navigationbar

I am trying to move the navigation to the upper right corner of the site but  the navigation is not responding and is stuck below the logo. I have tried adding `display: flex` to the UL, Nav and other divs as well as `position: relative`. I have also applied `justify-content: space-between` to try and space out the elements but they are still packed together. Here is a sandbox environment where all the code lives. Any help would be appreciated!

[Sandbox URL](http://dev-wisco-radio.pantheonsite.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding this flex attribute will help you achieve such thing.

```
.site-header {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

That will help making logo on the left & navigation on the right.
But to make the navigation really top right corner. You need to apply this

```
    .main-navigation {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        /* just add this line */
        align-self: flex-start;
    }
```

You can refer to this link for learning how each flex attribute will work

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I also had to add `#primary-menu > li {
    padding: 0 20px;
}` to make sure the items weren't stacked right next to each other

Comment: @bbestul: Yes, it's one way to do that or you can also use slacks for the menu items

Comment: @bbestul Sorry I mean flex

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning shouldn't be used for placement - what you're looking for is `absolute` positioning.

An `absolute` positioned element will be positioned from it's closest `relative` parent (or the `document.body`).

```
.menu-main-menu-container {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

The `space-between` issue will happen because your width is currently equal to the width of your content. If you wish to space these items apart you should either increase the width of your `.menu-main-menu-container` element, or add padding to your list items (I would suggest the latter)

```
#primary-menu > li {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE before anything else make sure you remove any flexbox or float you did before.

Now you have to edit your Wordpress template and move the whole **nav** after the **body** but before the **div id="page"** as its shown below.

```
<body class="home blog wp-custom-logo hfeed" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
            <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false"><li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-14"><a href="http://dev-wisco-radio.pantheonsite.io/2018/06/08/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://dev-wisco-radio.pantheonsite.io/sample-page-3/">sample page</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://dev-wisco-radio.pantheonsite.io/sample-page-2/">sample page</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://dev-wisco-radio.pantheonsite.io/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div id="page" class="site">
```

**and then place this code on your custom wordpress CSS**

```
#primary-menu{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 10px;
   right: 0;
   text-align: right;
}
#site-navigation{
  float: right;
}
```

> you can see how is working on this pen
>   [GO TO CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jeanbelmont/pen/YjrGYR/top)